# Puppet Unknown variable: 'osfamily' on Rocky 9

Tags: puppet, redhat, rocky-os

I am seeing the following error...

```
Error: Evaluation Error: Unknown variable: 'osfamily'. (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/print_text.pp, line: 1, column: 4) on node mgmtserver.mydomain.com
```

...when attempting to run a manifest on the Puppet Server...

`puppet apply /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/print_text.pp`

The manifest is:

```
if $osfamily == 'RedHat' {
   notice("A test message")
}
```

The following returns results...

`puppet facts osfamily`

```
{
  "osfamily": "RedHat"
}
```

...as does the following:

`facter osfamily`

```
RedHat
```

The Puppet Server is:

- OS: Rocky version 9
- Family: RedHat
- Puppet version: 8.5.0

puppetserver.service (master) is running on the host but puppet.service (agent) is not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Facts used to be accessible as top-scope variables.  That's been deprecated for some time, and I guess now it no longer works at all.  I'm not sure offhand when the feature was removed.  Note well that this has nothing in particular to do with the host OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are attempting to resolve a fact, then you would need to access the fact's value. The syntax `$osfamily` would instead attempt to resolve a value assigned to the variable `osfamily` which is undefined in your accessible scope. This can be accomplished with the following syntax:

```
if $facts['os']['family'] == 'RedHat' {
  notice("A test message")
}
```

Note the [documentation](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/lang_facts_accessing#lang_facts_accessing-fact-hash-syntax) also contains this as an example.

Comment: Thanks, that works. This manifest was part of my attempt to troubleshoot why PuppetDB is not installing. I followed the [documentation](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/puppetdb/readme) and executed `puppet module install puppetlabs-puppetdb --version 7.13.0` on the Puppet Server. However, the same error occurs after adding the [documented code](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/puppetdb/readme#single-node-setup) to the manifest.

Comment: I should add that the error occurs in `/modules/firewall/manifests/params.pp` file where the PuppetDB module is attempting to update the firewall `class firewall::params {
  $package_ensure = 'present'
  case $::osfamily {
    'RedHat': {
      case $::operatingsystem {`

Answer (score 1):

These are "legacy facts" in Puppet 8 :

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/wiki/Puppet-8-Compatibility#legacy-facts

Use the structured fact `os.family` instead, as in the accepted answer, using syntax `$facts['os']['family']`